Fail to start EurekaServer: 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' in your configuration. spring cloud netflix
We're migrating from Eureka server from Spring boot 2.x to 3.x to resolve vulnerabilities.
Facing issue only when deploying in server but in local application comes up without any problem.
Field applicationInfoManager in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' in your configuration.
Following are the contents in my pom file.
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-eurekaserver</artifactId>
    <version>${build.version}.${build.number}</version>
    <name>xyz-eurekaserver</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    

YML FILE
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:"
server:
  port: 8061

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8061/eureka}
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 15
    preferIpAddress: true
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: true

Tried following solutions in yml
1.spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled=false 2.eureka.client.serviceUrl.registerWithEureka=false
3. Used spring boot and cloud 3.x latest versions.
Can anyone let me know how to resolve the issue?
